# Purchasing bitcoins online

Tags: transactions, buy-bitcoins

**Is anybody aware of websites that are secure and reliable which will sell BTC promptly?** I made the rounds around my city today, but all of the BTC ATMs were tapped, and I'm beginning to feel a little helpless as I continue to watch the price grow and grow and grow...

Answer (score 1):

there are lot of grate websites where you can buy bitcoin..

example: coinbase.com, blockchain.info

https://www.bitcoin.com/buy-bitcoin <-- here are some ways to buy
http://cryptosort.com/wallet <-- here you could find something as well..

but if you are starter i suggest you to use coinbase, because there is simple interface and 3 cryptocurrencies available :)

Comment: mm.. yes.. you will need to verify identity but it takes seconds :) 
yeah, you can buy them there but probably some of them are scammers so be careful..

mm.. when i made my first wallet at coinbase i think it took max 30min to set it up and verify so.. :)

Comment: it only takes second to create an account, verify identify, and start buying BTC on coinbase?!?!?! It should be noted that I have my own Bitcoin Core wallet. i would never wanna store my BTC in an exchange after what happened before.

Answer (score 1):

I buy Bitcoins and trade on [Paxful](https://paxful.com/roots/buy-bitcoin?affiliate=ePndm2w5Y56)

They have Escrow and 24/7 support & Moderators as well.

They have guides on how to buy bitcoin as well:

Comment: thanks i'll def check it out. if i were to buy BTC on Paxful, i could get it sent to my wallet right?